# Powershell - Create Volatile Registry key?

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a volatile registry key (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms891450(v=msdn.10)) in a Powershell script?  I'm not sure if it's possible from the reading I've done.  Does anyone have any code if it is possible?

Comment: You know that the link you provided is for `Windows CE 5.0` ?

Comment: This API also exists in regular Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you looking for but you can use this command in CMD or powershell:

```
reg add "HKCU\Volatile Environment" /v MyVolatilVariable /d MyVolatilVariabledata /t reg_sz
```

Comment: Good thinking! This would certainly do.  I guess it's only user specific rather than machine but for my purposes it should be OK.  Thanks.

Comment: this is a permanent registry key, not a volatile one.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this commandline tool (with or without Powershell) to create volatile registry keys:
https://github.com/christian-korneck/mkmemkey